# Cycle index of a graph automorphism group

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, combinatorica

I want the cycle index of the group of automorphisms of a (say 3 X 3) grid graph.  I can produce the elements of the group with:

```
GroupElements[GraphData[{"Grid", {3, 3}}, "AutomorphismGroup"]]
```

This gives me:

```
{Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 4}, {3, 7}, {6, 8}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 9}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 3, 9, 7}, {2, 6, 8, 4}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 7, 9, 3}, {2, 4, 8, 6}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}}], Cycles[{{1, 9}, {2, 6}, {4, 8}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 9}, {2, 8}, {3, 7}, {4, 6}}]}
```

What I want is something like:  $1/8(s_1^9 + 4s_2^3 4s_1^3 + 2s_4^2 s_1 + s_2^4 s_1) $.

The problem seems to be that `CycleIndex`  `Needs["Combinatorica`"]`.

Comment: Take a look at `CycleIndexPolynomial`, which is a builtin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CycleIndexPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CycleIndexPolynomial.html) like so:

```
CycleIndexPolynomial[
 GraphAutomorphismGroup@GridGraph[{3, 3}],
 Array[Subscript[s, #] &, 4]
]
```

> $$ \frac{s_1^9}{8}+\frac{1}{2} s_2^3 s_1^3+\frac{1}{8} s_2^4 s_1+\frac{1}{4} s_4^2 s_1 $$

Comment: OK Thank you.  I will mention the following as a "possible issue" because it happened to me and caused much aggravation.  It is sometimes necessary to specify the "domain of action" (see help section for CycleIndexPolynomial).  For example: CycleIndexPolynomial[GraphData[{5, 32}, "AutomorphismGroup"],  Table[Subscript[s, i], {i, 1, 8}]]  does NOT return the correct polynomial.  A 5 must be added as a third argument in CylceIndexPolynomial.